# Using ByteBuffer as a JWT claim

Tags: java, json, jwt

I am using a JWT token and I have one of the claims to be a ByteBuffer. The JWT is generated successfully, but when I try to parse the JWT token and verify the claim, the it complains that the claimSet has no value.

Here's how my code looks:

```
        ByteBuffer encryptedText = getEncryptedTextAsByteBuffer();

        Instant timestamp = timestampSupplier.get();
        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
        claimsSet.setAudience("test-audience");
        claimsSet.setIssuer("test-issuer");
        claimsSet.setNotBeforeTime(Date.from(timestamp));
        claimsSet.setExpirationTime(Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(expirationTimestamp)));
        claimsSet.setClaim("myObject", encryptedText );

        PlainJWT jwt = new PlainJWT(claimsSet);
        return jwt.serialize();
```

The Validation Code looks like this:

```
        PlainJWT jwtToken = PlainJWT.parse(jwtToken);
        ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet claimsSet = jwtToken.getJWTClaimsSet();
        Map<String, Object> claims = claimsSet.getAllClaims();
        ByteBuffer encryptedText = (ByteBuffer) claims.get("myObject");
```

The exception message I see is this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.nio.ByteBuffer
```

I added a debugger and saw that the Jwt generation has a valid non empty ByteBuffer but the resultant claim has the "myObject" key but the value is an empty json String. Can we not use the claim as a byteBuffer? Or am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `claims.get("myObject")` is returning `JSONObject` object but you are casting it to  `ByteBuffer`. Try to get it `JSONObjectencryptedText = (JSONObject) claims.get("myObject");` and see what that JSONObject contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ByteBuffer contains binary data, but JSON is text format. You need to encode the underlying byte array to base64, and include it as a claim of the JWT

I am pretty new to ByteBuffer, so I reviewed javadoc to see how it works. Please try this

```
// ByteBuffer to base64
 byte[] data = new byte[encryptedText.remaining()]
 encryptedText.get(data);
 String dataB64 = DataTypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);

 //Add claim
 claimsSet.setClaim("myObject", dataB64);
```

To validate it, convert from base64 to byte[]. I think in this case it is not needed the ByteBuffer, but you can build it from byte[]

```
 String dataB64 = (String) claims.get("myObject");
 byte data[] = DataTypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(dataB64)
```

Comment: Don't use `DataTypeConverter`. Use `java.util.Base64`.

Answer (score 0):

That answer helped. Here's the modification I made to make the code work:

```
    ByteBuffer encryptedText = getEncryptedTextAsByteBuffer();
    String encodedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedText .array());
    Instant timestamp = timestampSupplier.get();
    JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
    claimsSet.setAudience("test-audience");
    claimsSet.setIssuer("test-issuer");
    claimsSet.setNotBeforeTime(Date.from(timestamp));
    claimsSet.setExpirationTime(Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(expirationTimestamp)));
    claimsSet.setClaim("myObject", );

    PlainJWT jwt = new PlainJWT(claimsSet);
    return jwt.serialize();
```

The Validation portion was changed to:

```
    PlainJWT jwtToken = PlainJWT.parse(jwtToken);
    ReadOnlyJWTClaimsSet claimsSet = jwtToken.getJWTClaimsSet();
    String claim = (String)claimsSet.getClaim("myObject");
    byte[] emailBinary = Base64.getDecoder().decode(claim);
```